# Error fitting a model in nls

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting, nls

previous answers to similar questions have not help me to solve my problem.

I am trying to fit a model `y=a1*(1-exp(-a21*Age_WH40))^a3`, where `a21=ln(1/a3)/a2`, and Age_WH40 goes from 1 to 40.
I've plot the data and a line to get an idea of the starting values

```
plot(MOE_WH40 ~ Age_WH40)
lines(ts(8*(1-exp(log(1/3)/5*(1:40)))^3),col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

```
fit.nlm_MOE4A.WH <- nls(MOE_WH40 ~ a*(1-exp(log(1/c)/b*Age_WH40))^b, start=list(a=10, b=6, c=2))
```

but even if I restrict the data to avoid dispersion I only get

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>     Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

I do not think it is a problem with the starting values, and I have run the model from 1 to 40 in Excel with no problem. Any idea what is happening? Here there is a subset of the data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 
252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 
263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 508L, 509L, 510L, 
511L), MOE_WH40 = c(7.9, 7.12, 4.369, 5.44, 8.97, 9.58, 8.07, 
7.9, 6.93, 5.63, 6, 6.17, 8.51, 8.79, 7.21, 6.64, 6.7, 7.88, 
7.97, 6.93, 5.64, 6.86, 9.36, 9.44, 10.04, 9.58, 4.337, 5.12, 
6.7, 7.86), Age_WH40 = c(23L, 29L, 4L, 8L, 13L, 20L, 24L, 29L, 
33L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 15L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 23L, 3L, 
9L, 16L, 22L, 26L, 30L, 2L, 8L, 11L, 15L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"MOE_WH40", "Age_WH40"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you @Zheyuan Li, I was struggling to put the data in a nice way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the minpack.lm package which uses the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm. I've called your data "demo" for brevity.

```
nlsLM(data = demo, formula = MOE_WH40 ~ a*(1-exp(log(1/c)/b*Age_WH40))^b, start=list(a=10, b=6, c=2))
Nonlinear regression model
model: MOE_WH40 ~ a * (1 - exp(log(1/c)/b * Age_WH40))^b
data: demo
 a      b      c 
8.5573 0.3774 1.0347 
residual sum-of-squares: 32.89

Number of iterations to convergence: 24 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
Warning messages:
1: In log(1/c) : NaNs produced
2: In log(1/c) : NaNs produced
3: In log(1/c) : NaNs produced
```

In nls it's always the starting values.

Comment: Thank you @biomiha. It solved this problem. 
However, if I try to fit the model using the coefficients calculated to avoid the log expression like "model <- nls(MOE_WH40 ~ a*(1-exp(-b*Age_WH40))^c, start=list(a=8, b=0.03, c=0.3))" I still get the same error...any thoughts?

Comment: In nls this is usually due to one or several of the coefficients not converging. Looking at your data, there is considerable variability in your data points, i.e. you could fit several different curves to the data. Can you try a simpler model to fit?

Comment: Yes @biomiha. I have fit different curves. The one shown was only one more. It makes sense to keep it simple, thanks.